# JSF 2 Default DateTime Converter Pattern

Tags: jsf, converters, datetime-format

My JSF pages display DateTime from managed beans in this format: "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"

I want avoid duplicate converter declaration in different pages: `<f:convertDateTime type="both" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a" dateStyle="short" timeStyle="medium" />`

Is there a way to make the above converter default for all DateTime fields?

(Experience with JSF 2: 2 months.)

Comment: consider writing custom converter , that way you will be able to reuse it as many time as you want...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just extend the [`DateTimeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html) class behind `<f:convertDateTime>` and set the defaults in the constructor.

```
@FacesConverter("defaultDateConverter")
public class DefaultDateConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    public DefaultDateConverter() {
        setPattern("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a");
    }

}
```

Use it as `<f:converter converterId="defaultDateConverter" />`

Please note that I omitted other attributes as they are ignored anyway when `pattern` is specified.

Comment: How would one modify this converter to accept null dates

Comment: Be careful if you do this while using Omnifaces, DefaultDateConverter is now going to be used everywhere you use `<f:convertDateTime>` also.

Comment: JSF should allow this to be set by a web.xml context param, so no need to extend it