# Configuring Timezone in web.xml Java Web Application

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm working with JSF 2.0 + Primefaces + Tomcat + Maven + JPA, and in my web.xml I have this piece of code:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

With this I hope that value of "convertDateTime" should show normally, but in database I have this: "04/01/2014 15:10" and in application show this: "04/01/2014 03:10".

How can I fix it ?

EDIT 1:

If I use in this way, then everything works:

```
<f:convertDateTime timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
```

But I want to avoid change all my tags to insert "timeZone='America/Sao_Paulo'". Is there another way?

**SOLUTION**

The solution is more easy than I imagine. I just changed the "hh:mm:ss" pattern to "HH:mm:ss". The "hh" lowercase was the problem because this just show 12H and not 24H.

Comment: That's not timezone issue but presentation issue due to Locale.

Comment: How can i fix it and which the difference between locale and timezone ?

Comment: Related: [JSF 2 Default DateTime Converter Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14990960/1065197).

Comment: I don't wanna change all my tags to: <f:converter converterId="defaultDateConverter" />

Comment: There's no other option.

Comment: Please, see my edit in post.

Answer (score -2):

You can change default timezone in web.xml. Just add:

```
 <context-param><param-name>timezone</param-name>
 <param-value>America/Sao_Paulo</param-value></context-param>
```

and remove javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE